# Script breaks because index not present in a list

Tags: python

This is my piece of code:

```
actual = self.new_data[i][aa]
try:
   act_loc = Functions.conv_simb[actual]
except ValueError:
   Functions.handle_error(self, message=ValueError)
   return
```

and this is the list:

```
conv_simb = {"P": "P", "M": "M", "S": "S", "CM": "D", "CP": "E", "CS": "T", "VP": "F", "VM": "G", "VS": "R",
             "MP": "W", "MM": "Z", "EN": "U", "PM": "H", "PP": "L", "EM": "A", "EP": "B", "ES": "SE", "AM": "I",
             "AP": "J", "AS": "K", "BM": "N", "BP": "O", "BS": "Q", "X": "X", "--": "V", "XZX": "Y", "":""}
```

The user can edit a cell in a QWidegetTable and introduce a value in [actual] which is not in the above list, suppose [actual = 'd']. I cant catch the error so the program correctly breaks with

```
act_loc = Functions.conv_simb[actual]
KeyError: 'd'
```

Comment: Well it throws `KeyError`, not `ValueError`.

Comment: `conv_simb` is not a `list`, it is a Python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (or `dict`), which maps keys to values.  It apparently does not contain the key `'d'` (it does have upper-case `'D'`) but dict keys much match exactly.

Comment: What exactly is your expectation here? As your output shows (and as is to be expected from a ``dict``) the error is ``KeyError``, not ``ValueError``. If you expected the ``try:`` ``except:`` to handle this error, then... handle this error. If not, what else do you want to happen instead?

Comment: @Guy. Thank you sir. I read all the possible Errors but KeyError. This thread should be closed

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `.get` and supply a default value:

```
act_loc = Functions.conv_simb.get(actual, "value if key not found")
```